# How to determine if average is 0 vs null?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've got a Mongo database where I run some aggregation queries. Here's the simplified query I want to run:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
 { $group: { 
   _id: 'fieldA', 
   fieldB: { $avg: '$fieldB' } 
 } },
])
```

It groups data by fieldA and calculates average for fieldB. Anyway, some rows in result set have 0 as value for fieldB. There can be 2 reasons for that:

1. Average value IS 0.
2. All documents in a group didn't have fieldB (or had null as a value); and Mongo behavior  is to return 0 in that case.

Is it possible to determine which scenario took place for each row in resulting selection without issuing other query and without leaving aggregation pipeline?

**UPDATE**

I can't filter out non-null fields, as I'm doing aggregation for few fields, like that:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
 { $group: { 
   _id: 'fieldA', 
   fieldB: { $avg: '$fieldB' },
   fieldC: { $avg: '$fieldC' } 
 } },
])
```

Some of the documents may have fieldB but not fieldC and vice versa.

Comment: Add a `$match` to the pipeline to filter the documents that should not be included in the `$avg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the data by using `$match` before your `$group` operation.

```
db.coll.aggregate([
 { $match: { fieldB : {$ne : null }}}},
 { $group: { 
   _id: 'fieldA', 
   fieldB: { $avg: '$fieldB' } 
 } },
])
```

This way you will get only documents that have `fieldB` set.

**UPDATE**

You can't use the `$avg` that way but you can find out if all values are `NULL` using [$min](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) operator:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
 { $group: { 
   _id: 'fieldA', 
   fieldB: { $avg: '$fieldB' } , 
   fieldBAllNullOrMin: { $min: '$fieldB' } 
 } },
])
```

The `$min` operator will return `null` if **all** values are **null**, otherwise it will return min. value (but only in 2.4+ versions of MongoDB).

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work in my case, as I'm calculating few averages at the same time

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using?

I have tried the $avg function on 2.4.6 and it counts average value only for the docs that have value for that key.

http://pastebin.com/cHg9tdBY

Comment: I've got 2.4.7. Please see a link - http://pastebin.com/9KjSETEs Here I calculate average for 'x' and 'y' fields. 'x' is calculated correctly, but 'y' returns 0 as input documents don't have 'y' at all. While 0 seems to be perfectly valid value, there's no way to determine in a single query if it's 0 because values are 0 or because values are nulls (don't exist)

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. Upvoting your answer, but other answer with the same solution appeared earlier, so I marked that one as correct

Comment: @YuraTaras Just to be precise I answered the question and then edited it to add the UPDATE. My update was at 14:47:27Z - other question was posted at 15:09:23Z.

Comment: this answer is wrong - leaving the $match for non-null fields means you will filter out the entire documents which have this field as null but other fields that need to be counted.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky you're right, forgot to remove the $match from the updated part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the $max (or $min) operator to determine whether all
instances of fieldB in a group are null or missing, as the $max (or
$min) operator return null in that case. Given this aggregation
pipeline:

```
c.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: '$fieldA',
        avg: {$avg: '$fieldB'},
        max: {$max: '$fieldB'},
    }}
])
```

with these documents:

```
c.insert({fieldA: 1, fieldB: 3})
c.insert({fieldA: 1, fieldB: -3})
```

the result is:

```
{"_id": 1, "avg": 0, "max": 3}
```

whereas with these documents:

```
c.insert({fieldA: 1})
c.insert({fieldA: 1})
```

the result is:

```
{"_id": 1, "avg": 0, "max": null}
```

The null value for the max field tells you that fieldB was null or
missing in all documents in the group.

Hope this helps,

Bruce